# Django 1.9.2 + jQuery + POST - Error 403 - CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: jquery, python, django, post

i'm new to django, I'm trying to fire simple function from views.py by clicking button on webpage. That's what I've done:

HTML:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-circle btn-primary btn-xl" id="add_address_button"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
</form>

    $('#add_address_button').click( function() {
        $.post("adres/add_address_button_action/", function () {
            alert('OK');
        });
    });
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^adres/add_address_button_action/$',views.add_address_button_action, name = 'add_address_button_action'),
```

views.py

```
def add_address_button_action(request):    
    adres = get_object_or_404(Adres, id =2) 
    return render(request, 'serwis/address_detail.html', RequestContext(request,  {'address_detail_zmienna': adres}))
```

Information from terminal:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /adres/add_address_button_action/ 
...
"POST /adres/add_address_button_action/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2274
```

I was trying different return in views.py:

```
return render_to_response('serwis/address_detail.html', RequestContext(request, {'address_detail_zmienna': adres}))
return redirect('serwis/address_detail.html', {'address_detail_zmienna': adres})
```

But none of them works.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me figure that out.
I've read lots of topics regarding this issue, but most of them are out dated - and didn't help.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you look in chrome dev tools? Did you verify that the token is exist in your html? Did you inspect the post request? Is it contains the token as well?

Comment: Another thing, doesnt related to django but to js / html / jQuery. If you are using button with type submit you don't need to add click handler as well. The type submit trigger post request.. The second post request (by jQuery) might sent without the desired token

Comment: if I use chrome dev tools this elements looks like that: <form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="dkKN19Gc2XGOSZm2iXXQ5SFh5u3xdPIO">. So as far as I understand the token is included... I added click handler to call django function..

Comment: No, use 'action' attribute instead

Comment: And look for the request header in chrome dev tool (in network tab) see if the token passed to the server..

Comment: Good news! I've used action attribute as you said:<form role="form" method="post"  action = "{% url 'add_address_button_action' %}">{% csrf_token %} and in views.py: return render(request, 'serwis/address_detail.html', {'address_detail_zmienna': adres}, RequestContext(request)) and it redirects me to the page address_detail.html :). So the problem seems to be solved :) Thank you!

Comment: I've added answer that summarize our discussion here. It would be great if you accept my answer (green V) so I'll get my reputation. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of a day I've followed this tutorial:

https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/06/16/django-with-ajax-a-modern-client-server-communication-practise/

and that works very well.

Thank you all for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you aren't passing the CSRF token to the server. Check out [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it).

You need to either pre-configure your jQuery to pass the csrf token in the header of every AJAX request you make, or you need to explicitly pass the CSRF token as data to the $.post() function.

Detailed code is available in the above linked documentation.

Comment: To be honest I thought that have been done in first line with "{% crsf token %}"... If I get it right I should add to my project functions from 'Ajax' part of this document - but where? I should create new static file and include it to my project with another externaj js/jquery files?

Comment: What I usually do is have a global "ajax_util.js" file which is sourced first in the heads of all of my webpages which need to perform ajax requests. Set the header there using the code on the Django site, and you will be good to go.

Comment: Ok, so I will place all the code in 'ajax_util.js', but what next, i should add jQuery listener to click event on the button and call django function with it? It would be the better way (because using AJAX) than one mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to look in chrome developers tool:

1. Did you verify that the token is exist in your html?
2. Did you inspect the post request? Is it contains the token as well?

The problem here is related to js / html / jQuery. If you are using button with type submit you don't need to add click handler as well. Button with `type="submit"` trigger post request.. The second post request (by jQuery) looks redundant and sent without the desired token (otherwise you'll pass it).

I suggest to use 'action' attribute:

```
<form method="post" action="adres/add_address_button_action/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-circle btn-primary btn-xl" id="add_address_button"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
</form>
```

Now it should work..